# Why my php codes doesn't run when called from submit botton of html form?

Tags: php, html

When I run the same code by typing file's address in Browser's address bar it runs perfectly.But when I run it via html file code doesn't work.The part within  doesn't work whereas the code outside this tag is displayed.
[THis is my php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kpg4.jpg)[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FEnR.jpg)

Comment: If you inspect the source, do you see the PHP-code as its written?

Comment: Is it uploaded to a web server? PHP requires a web server to be run, it cannot run locally.

Comment: Yes..I see the exact php code as written @Qirel

Comment: Yes..I am uisng XAMPP @Carter